# jQuery Mobile How to prevent a page from going to the default state when refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Mobile (**no php or xml or anything else**) for a web application running on cherrypy and i would like to find out how can i keep the page as it has been set by user even after refreshing.

As an example of the page, see this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/xaKXM/5/
in this example, user may input certain text in `Response number` and `description`. When the user click submit,user will see `#configtable div`. if the page is refreshed, user will not go back to the initial page (`#labels div' )but to remain in the`#configtable` (the one that user can't input anything but can only click activate button")

May be there is a button that would clear all those states and the page will go back to default when refresh?

Is this possible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

if you refresh the DOM using `window.open('index.html');` this should clear everything in the page

Comment: use web storage. localStorage.setItem("myvalue", "xxxx"); or just change the page with $.mobile.changePage("#newpage")

Comment: hi! fyi, i have everything in a page, i simple show and hide them... is it still possible?